# Multiple linear regression models using data.table and patterns with grep

Tags: r, data.table, regression

I'm trying to use a single data.table to run multiple linear regression models using a pattern `grep()` and applying the model to each part of the table using `by=`

This is what I got so far.

```
 d <- data.table(label=rep(c('a','b','c'),
c(10,10,10)),resp1=rnorm(30),resp2=rnorm(30),x1=runif(30),x2=runif(30))

    for (i in grep('resp',names(d),value = TRUE)) {

    models[i] <- d[,as.list(coef(lm(i ~ x1 + x2 ))),by=label]}
```

then I get the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = eval(i) ~ x1 + x2,
>   drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :    variable lengths differ (found for
>   'x1')

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious.. And I can see the the `by` argument is not working when using the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make below changes to make it work inside `data.table`. The problem with your setup is that `i` gets converted to `"resp1"` (resp1 with quotes) in the for loop, which is not desirable for the formula, also in case of data.table
`lm` tries for the variables used in the environment of the formula supplied, Since there is no "data" element inside lm argument, R has no way to determine from which place/environment these variables are coming hence, you need to supply .SD (subset of data in data.table),this can be found in the second expression element in data.table( we usually refer that as j expression) hence you have to use `$` or `[[` explicitly here.

Assuming "d" is your data.table then do this:

```
models <- list()  ###Initialize the list where you want to save your outcome.
for (i in grep('resp',names(d),value = TRUE)) { 
  models[[i]] <- d[,as.list(coef(lm(.SD[[i]] ~ .SD$x1 + .SD$x2 ))),by=label]
}
```

To call their values, you need to do this:

```
models[["resp1"]]  and/or  models[["resp2"]]
```

**Output:**

```
# label (Intercept)         x1         x2
# 1:     a   1.0189543 -1.3744124 -1.8500784
# 2:     b  -1.7325901  0.6330311  0.7848932
# 3:     c   0.3497773 -0.9138042  0.7833840
# > models[["resp2"]]
# label (Intercept)         x1        x2
# 1:     a -0.89177938  1.1053718 0.8886103
# 2:     b -0.45480510 -0.5146982 1.5587663
# 3:     c -0.04379456 -0.9792022 0.8691384
```